# How to make rooms for game with Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-socketio

I am using Flask-SocketIO on server and socketIO-client on PC.
After starting the application on PC, it sends request for getting code of the room:

```
socketIO = SocketIO('192.168.43.217', 8080)

def get_code(code):
    submit_code = code
    print('code =', code)


socketIO.emit('new_room')
socketIO.on('get_code', get_code)
socketIO.wait()
```

Server sends code:

```
@socketio.on('new_room')
def new_room():

    code = randint(1000, 9999)

    db.session.add(Rooms(code))
    db.session.commit()
    emit('get_code', code)
```

I added `socketio.emit('new_user', current_user.name)` after user's, and that code sends name to PC-client.

But if i create two or more rooms, i see, that same user logged in different room.

How can i make something like `socketio.emit('new_user', current_user.name, namespace=f'/{room_code}')`? 
That will emit only to the right room.

Or this is not right way?
After that, game will starts, PC-client will show answers, players will get some answers from PC, then sends it back like this:

1) The code is generated on the server and the computer is returned

2) A person from another device enters a code, his nickname and connects

3) He appears in the room

4) A record appears on the computer that it is connected

5) The game begins, the task is displayed

6) Answer options come to phones

7) The computer shows who answered, well, then there is already purely game logic. Calculation of points and other things

Comment: I am also locking for a way to store objects between multiple users for a multi room environment. Did you also store the game-logic object into that db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you generate a room, you should add the client to it by calling:

```py
from flask_socketio import enter_room

@socketio.on('new_room')
def new_room():

    code = randint(1000, 9999)
    enter_room(str(code))

    db.session.add(Rooms(code))
    db.session.commit()
    emit('get_code', code)
```

Then you can send an event to the user in this room with:

```
socketio.emit('new_user', current_user.name, room=str(room_code))
```